# Any Silverlight UML diagramming tools available?

Tags: silverlight, uml

This might be a long shot, but I'm curious if there are any Silverlight components out there that provide UML-editing capabilities.  I'm interested in allowing users to make use-case diagrams and model workflows, among other things.  I'm using Silverlight 4 if it matters.

Thanks!

**Edit**

Free or open-source options are definitely preferable, though commercial ones will be considered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for commercial solution, may be you could try 
[Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/silverlight/diagram) and Online Demo is [here](http://silverlight.syncfusion.com/samples/silverlight/9.1.0.20/default.aspx?sample=diagram).

Comment: Free or open-source would be best, but thanks, I'll check it out